# Styling multiple images using css/bootstrap

Tags: css, laravel-8

I am trying to display multiple images for displaying in my booking system but the images are simply appearing in one column like this

[image: Resulting display]

While this is how I expected them to appear
[image: Expected display]
So far I am using bootstrap to style the images.
What I want is to loop through the returned images and show the first three in the first row then the second four in the following row showing the number of all that are hidden in the last column of the last row just as in the image

So far this is what I have been able to do

```
     <div class="card-body">
        <div class="portfolio-area">
            
            @foreach ($images as $image)
            <div>
                <span class="image-block block2">
                <a class="image-zoom" href="{{ asset('uploads/property/large/'.$image->path) }}" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">                            
                        <img src="{{ asset('uploads/property/small/'.$image->path) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="CEC Gallery"></a>
            </span>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is how I am returning the images

```
    $images = Photo::where(['p_id'=>$property_id])->get();
```

Any help on how I can loop through and style the images is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Is so much easy.. first you need to use laravel chunk visit: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-chunk

then you need two type of design, that you shown.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how I could use that for my case coz I am not so familiar with the method

Comment: This method helps to that you  want to display in a grid

Comment: I have been able to chunk them but how do I get to introduce the second design?

Comment: After chunking, I am looping through the chunks as shown ``` @foreach ($image as $item)
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div>
                            <span>
                            <a class="image-zoom" href="{{ asset('uploads/property/large/'.$item->path) }}" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]">       
                                    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/property/small/'.$item->path) }}"></a>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach```

Comment: Ok. it is a simple trick

{{--@foreach ($your_collections->chunk(3) as  $key=> $chunk_variable)--}}
{{--    <div class="row">--}}
{{--        @foreach ($chunk_variable as $example)--}}
{{--            @if($key === 0)--}}
{{--                <p>Here your first design</p>--}}
{{--            @else--}}
{{--                <p>Here your second design</p>--}}
{{--            @endif--}}
{{--        @endforeach--}}
{{--    </div>--}}
{{--@endforeach--}}